# Math в C#: документация или пример

Tags: c#

Подскажите хорошую документацию, урок или сами объясните о том? какие действия можно производить с помощью Math.

Comment: Ну, очевидно: математические =) Хотите - берите синус. Хотите - косинус... Можно даже тангенс. Или корень. Или степень. Или ещё что-нибудь. Можно даже всё вместе)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! [Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4zfefwz9(v=VS.100).aspx) касательно класса "System.Math" на msdn.